# parse xml in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, unix, scripting

In my xml I have a particular field like below I want to get the select query and use it in my script again.Sometime the query is very long and have new line also. This is embedded into an xml  .

Below are the part of the xml I want to extract , it is not the complete xml.I want to read the xml and then take out the part start with text and from that extract the query.

Or **lets say I want to extract the part between the text="  *till*  "> .**

```
text="select * from dual">
text="select * from xml_config">
text="select * from
       WHERE SOC_STATUS='A') sa,
       SUBSCRR sub,
       UH_TEMP_CUSTO leading
       where   (NVL(SA.EXRATION_DATE,SYSDATE) &gt;= SYSDATE - ${HISTORY_DAYS})
       AND sub.CUSTOMER_ID=LEADING.CUSTOMER_ID
       AND sa.AGREEMENT_NO = sub.SUBSCRIBER_NO
       AND SUB.EFFECTIVE_DATE!=NVL(SUB.EXRATION_DATE,SUB.EFFECTIVE_DATE+1) 
       ORDER BY sa.AGREEMENT_NO">

output:

    value[0] =select * from dual
    value[1]=select * from xml_config
    value[2]=select * from WHERE SOC_STATUS='A') sa,SUBSCRR sub,
             UH_TEMP_CUSTO leading where   (NVL(SA.EXRATION_DATE,SYSDATE) &gt;= SYSDATE - ${HISTORY_DAYS}) AND .CUSTOMER_ID=LEADING.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND sa.AGREEMENT_NO = sub.SUBSCRIBER_NO AND SUB.EFFECTIVE_DATE!=NVL(SUB.EXRATION_DATE,SUB.EFFECTIVE_DATE+1) 
    ORDER BY sa.AGREEMENT_NO
```

-Thanks

Comment: please use the `{}` button to format code and XML. I think something got mangled in your question, the XML part lacks some `<`, so please edit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your question, but the answer is [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).